# Split on codepoints in Perl 6

Tags: raku

How do I split on codepoints instead on grapheme clusters?

Sample:

```
"స్వాగతం".comb()
--> output (స్ వా గ తం)
```

How do I get the following?

```
 (స ్ వ ా గ త ం)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First convert to decomposed codepoints (`.NFD`), then convert back to graphemes again (`.chr`):

```
dd "స్వాగతం".NFD>>.chr  # ("స", "\x[c4d]", "వ", "ా", "గ", "త", "ం")
```

I'm not sure why `«్` is rendered as `"\x[c4d]"` here.  Perhaps this points to a bug.

Comment: `use strict; use utf8; binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)"; print "స" . "ా";` please translate this perl5 to perl6

Comment: `print "స" ~ ""ా" #  స"ా`.  In other words, use `~` instead of `.` ?  `use strict`, `use utf8` and `binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)"` are all set by default in Perl 6.  As far as I remember Perl 5, I must admit.

Comment: perl5 and perl6 outputs are different

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen: I think that's one quote character too many, so that second string is `"\x[0022]\x[0c3e]"`.

Comment: @rx57: Since Perl 6 source code is parsed at the grapheme level, I don't think you can represent a lone diacritical mark literally. Use an `\x[ ]` (hex character code) escape instead: `print "స" ~ "\x[0c3e]";`